# How to return subscribers from one user from youtube api?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I'm having a hard time trying to find it in the poor official documentation and in the community

any directions?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain, an integer to represent the amount of users subscribed to a user or a list of users that are subscribed to the user?

Comment: list of subscribers to a specific channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this [isn't possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/3rN_WDaMgTs) before the version 3.0 experimental API. If you're using the V3 API, you can get the [Channels list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and set the `mySubscribers` filter to `true`. Set the properties you want to retrieve in the `part` parameter (such as `contentDetails` which includes information such as the subscriber's Google+ ID). This filter is authorized so you need to have permission from the the user to call this method.